# Get value from ID and insert to input using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, input

I am new to JavaScript. I am getting result from label from another javascript. Now I want to send it to the input type hidden. Please help on how to do it

1. Below is the code that I am getting result from javascript

```
<label id="result"></label>
```

2. here i want to change the year input value to the above label id=result value. Please help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var post_title = new Date();
    document.getElementById("post_title").value=(post_title.getFullYear());
</script>   

<input type="hidden" name="post_title" id="post_title" class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: Where is the year input?

Comment: What does the label have to do with anything?

Comment: What is the specific issue you're having?

Comment: Depending on where that snippet is, `document.getElementById("post_title")` might execute before the input is actually in the markup. That should throw you something like this in the console **Cannot set property 'value' of null**.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest bringing your `<script>` element all the way to the bottom of your HTML so that the rest of the HTML loads and you can avoid any errors where the element does not exist (As @Lain said in the comments)

We can get the inner value of the `<label>` using

```
var label = document.getElementById("result");
var labelValue = label.innerHTML; //What this does is it returns a string of all HTML and text inside this element, in this case it would just be the value

//Then using the rest of your code, set the post_title to the label value
var post_title = document.getElementById("post_title");
post_title.value = labelValue;
```

All of the above belongs inside of your script tags, in case that wasn't clear

Let me know if that works or if that's what you're looking for

Comment: I need the label generate number to put in the input value. 

Example `<label id="result">5144</label>`

The 4 digit number is auto generated so I want to put that number in to the input value

Comment: My code does exactly that unless you want to remove the $ sign then you can use a JavaScript substring

Comment: Is that I just need to paste your code or I should edit the code? Sorry I am new to javascript.

Comment: Try using what i have and see if it works, let me know if it doesn't

Comment: <label id="result">Hi</label> I tried to put in this and I get the value="Hi" but the auto generate number doesn't goes to the value.

Comment: ```<label id="result">9195</label>```
```<input type="hidden" name="post_title" id="post_title" class="form-control" value="Number">```

As you can see the value didn't change. It only remain with the beginning text. not changing when the number got generated

Comment: How are you checking if it changes or not?

Comment: I manage to resolve it. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: What was the issue?